# Swap text between commas and among the colons

Tags: notepad++, editplus

i have a file that contain repetitive code like this an i just want to

swap a roll/column? (how to say?) of y and z  , every number is different in here nothing in here is same number

Example:

```
xxxx,xxxx,yyyy,xxxx,xxxx,zzzz:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:
xxxx,xxxx,yyyy,xxxx,xxxx,zzzz:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:
xxxx,xxxx,yyyy,xxxx,xxxx,zzzz:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:
xxxx,xxxx,yyyy,xxxx,xxxx,zzzz:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:
```

Into:

```
xxxx,xxxx,zzzz,xxxx,xxxx,yyyy:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:
xxxx,xxxx,zzzz,xxxx,xxxx,yyyy:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:
xxxx,xxxx,zzzz,xxxx,xxxx,yyyy:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:
xxxx,xxxx,zzzz,xxxx,xxxx,yyyy:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:
```

x , y , z = different numbers

sorry for poor explanation

example

```
 36,192,72004,128,0,71923:0:0:0:0:
 256,192,72014,128,0,71843:0:0:0:0:
 475,192,72204,128,0,71923:0:0:0:0:
```

to

```
 36,192,71923,128,0,72004:0:0:0:0:
 256,192,71843,128,0,72014:0:0:0:0:
 475,192,71923,128,0,72204:0:0:0:0:
```

Comment: You can use a regex find-and-replace for this. Assuming that all of the x's represent different numbers, the only thing to anchor your search against is the commas and colons. A substitution like `/([^,]*,)([^,]*)/` will match against `yyyy` in the second group.

Comment: @jpaugh I'm new to here. Thanks for help but i don't know how to use regex. I know only how to use the ctrl+h in editplus/notepad++

Comment: Notepad++ supports [regexs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regex), which is why I mentioned it. I recommend learning them if you have this sort of problem often. You can learn them in a few afternoons by reading up, and trying things out in your editor.

Comment: Welcome to [so]! This question would be a better fit for [su], but even there it might get down votes. Not sure.

Comment: your question is not about programming per-se, which is probably why it got down-voted. [SU] is about how to use applications, and is a better fit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

his should do the job (in Notepad++):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^((?:[^,]+,){2})(\d+),((?:[^,]+,){2})(\d+)`
- Replace with: `$1$4,$3$2`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^           : start of line
(           : start group 1
  (?:       : start non capture group
    [^,]+   : 1 or more non comma
    ,       : a comma
  ){2}      : end group, must appear twice
)           : end group 1 
(\d+)       : group 2, 1 or more digits 
,           : a comma
(           : start group 3
  (?:       : start non capture group
    [^,]+   : 1 or more non comma
    ,       : a comma
  ){2}      : end group, must appear twice
)           : end group 3
(\d+)       : group 4, 1 or more digits
```

**Replacement:**

```
$1$4,$3$2   : group 1 group 4  comma group 3 group 4
```

Comment: Does that work in Notepad++, or EditPlus, or some other editor?

Comment: Thankyou its working! Notepadd++ Search Mode : Regular Expression 
/ RegExr also working for this code!  thank you so much! btw Who is downvote my question lol?This will help me a lot of thing for my day

Comment: @jpaugh: It works in Npp, I don't know for other editors.